# Is there a way to recognize an item is a file or a directory?

Tags: iphone

I hope to know if there is a way to detect an item is a file or directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`-[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:]`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-CHDBFHAG)